# A load is thrown perpendicularly from a train moving on a straight fixed rail

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

Consider a hypothetical train of mass $m=2$ kg with a load of mass $M=48$ kg moving freely (with no external force along  forward/backward direction) at speed $v=1$ m/s on a straight fixed rail.

Suddenly, the load is perpendicularly ejected out of the train at speed $v=1/2$ m/s. The rail is good enough to keep the empty train moving forward.

What is the final speed of the train after the load is ejected?

My solution is as follows. Because no net force along forward/backward direction, the momentum of the system (train + load) is conserved.

\begin{align}
(m+M)v &=mv'\\
v'&= \frac{m+M}{m}v\\
&=\frac{2+48}{2}1\\
&=25
\end{align}

I know the energy is not conserved here. But I got surprised because the total kinetic energy of the system changes significantly from 25  joules to 631 joules.

Is my calculation correct?

Comment: Hi! I'd suggest you to perform the calculation in the frame where the system "train+load" is at rest before splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the load is ejected perpendicularly, there is no force exerted on the train in the direction of motion. Thus after ejection, the train moves on at the same speed as before, i.e. at 1 m/s. If you can disregard the resistance that the load experiences in air after ejection, also the load will continue to have the same speed components parallel to the train as before, i.e. 1 m/s.
Note: Momentum is conserved, but you wrongly assume that after ejection the total Momentum is only the momentum of the train.